# Sending a break below 0.25 seconds

Tags: linux, uart, ioctl

I am using the function tcsendbreak to send a break on a uart for a specific amount of time. My problem is, that this function has a minimum time amount of 0.25 seconds. I want to send a break for max 20ms and at least 12ms. How can I do that?

I have tried using ioctl(fd, TCSBRKP, duration) request to do the break as well, but it seems that it is the same function used in the tcsendbreak.

```
tcsendbreak (int __fd, int __duration)

ioctl (int __fd, unsigned long int __request, ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution!

```
//Send break for at least 12 ms
ioctl(fd, TIOCSBRK);
usleep(13000);
ioctl(fd, TIOCCBRK);
```